# Qt creator does not recognized Qt library objects

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I use ubuntu 20.04 and QtCreator 4.11.0. My Qt application builds ok, but Qt creator can not recognized it own libraries like QObjec, QCoreApplication, QQmlApplicationEngine, etc. Warnings are: /home/evgeny/QtProjects/Server/main.cpp:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'QCoreApplication' etc
[image]

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Server.pro

```
QT += quick core network

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

That must I do in this situation?

Comment: Did you check the configuration of the kit you are using in the preferences?

Comment: @LucaCarlon Yes, all is ok (IMHO)